# Mongodb multikey index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson

I want to make sure I'm creating the right index for my data structure (documents in mongodb).

My document contains **list of items**, and each item contain **list of locations**.
I'm searching for items using it's location, and I want to **create the right index** for this kind of search.

```
   { # <- document
      "items": [
           {   # <- first item
               "name": "Item Name",
               "locations": [
                    { # <- first location
                       "sw":{"lat":0, "lng":0},
                       "ne":{"lat":0, "lng":0},
                    },
                    { # <- second location
                       "sw":{"lat":0, "lng":0},
                       "ne":{"lat":0, "lng":0},
                    },
                    { # <- more locations...
                      ...
                    },
               ]
           },
           {   # <- second item
              ...
           }
      ]
   }
```

I'm searching for items using the **lat** and **lng** values, and I've used "ensureIndex" with the following key to create the index:

```
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({"items.locations.sw.lat":1});
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({"items.locations.sw.lng":1});
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({"items.locations.ne.lat":1});
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({"items.locations.ne.lng":1});
```

Is it the right way?

Thanks

Comment: You'd likely want to use a geospatial index for that: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/#geospatial-index

Comment: What is sw and ne ? I don't understand why you use 2 locations per item.

Comment: @kranteg south-east and north-west, 2 points that represent boundaries.

Comment: I'm sure it's not the right way but I don't find a way to do this. Perhaps use GeoJSON type MultiPoint : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#multipoint. Be careful with the order for coordinates, GeoJSON is working with longitude, latitude (opposite of your design). I add a tag GeoJSON to your question.

Comment: @kranteg, in Mongodb documentation - all samples related to geospatial/GeoJSON etc shows how to check if stored location is in box, polygon etc.
I'm trying to do the opposite - I have list of geo "boxes" stored in my db and I'm trying to search wich box contain specific location.